# how can i get foreach loop variable outside of loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the code of **wordpress custom plugin.**?

```
$pages = get_pages();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $pagee=$page->post_title;
}
echo $pagee; <---- I want here all pages name in variable.
```

please suggest how can i do it.

Comment: Declare the variable before the loop so it exists outside of the scope of the loop.  Though it's not really clear if what you're asking is what you actually want, because the value will *always* equal the very last value from the loop.

Comment: make `$pagee` an array and add to it each foreach loop? `$pagee[]=$page->post_title;`

Comment: What do you wanna achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just to append your variable like this

```
$pages = get_pages();
$pagee = array();
foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $pagee[] = $page->post_title;
}
echo implode(",",$pagee);
```

Comment: or If i want result in array than? because i want to store this details in database.


'global $wpdb;

        $table_name = 'wp_seo_code';

 
        $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_seo_code", array(

            "page" => $pagee,

            "code_true" => $code_true

        ));

        
        if ($success) {

            

            echo '<b style="color:green;"> Inserted successfully</b>';

            
        } else {

            echo 'Not';

        }'

Comment: Look at the edited code, now is working with array. If you want to store inside a db remember to access your array values by index.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it as an array

```
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    $pagee[]= $page->post_title; 
}  
print_r($pagee);
```

Eventually as long string

```
foreach ($pages as $page) { 
    $pagee.= $page->post_title . ' '; 
 }  
 echo $pagee;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
// To save all pages
$allpages = array();
$pages = get_pages();
  foreach ($pages as $page) {
    // function array_push to insert the data at the end of the array
    array_push($allpages, $page->post_title);
  }
// Show the array
print_r($allpages);
```

or this:

```
$i = 0; // counter
$allpages = array(); // array to save all pages
$pages = get_pages();
  foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $allpages[$i] = $page->post_title; // save the value in the array by an index
    $i++; // increment the counter
  }

print_r($allpages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring an array to store all values of `$pagee` while the loop runs:

```
$pages = get_pages();
$pagee = [];
foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $pagee[]=$page->post_title;
}
print_r($pagee); // print the array of all cycles
```

So, `$pagee` will contain all the values of `$pagee` for each cycle in the loop.

Comment: variables in a loop do not live in a different scope

Comment: @lovelace ah yes, I've made the appropriate edits, thanks